# Java Recursion - Did I do this right?

Tags: java, recursion

My job is to write a recursive version to this method. From what I understand Recursion is starting with a base call (if something then return) followed by an else which unwinds back to the original base. Like starting with a deck, adding on to the deck then removing cards from the deck until you are back to the original deck.
With that in mind here it is.

```
public static long fact(int n)
{
    long result = 1;
    while(n > 0)
    {
         result = result * n;
         n = n - 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

//my recursive version:

```
public static void recFact(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return n; // ir 0 it really doesn't matter right?
    }
    else
    {
        return recFact(n-1);
    }
}
```

This is just an example test problem for an exam I have coming up, just want to make sure I have a handle on recursion. Did I do this right? If not what am I missing? please no answers in questions, just tell me what I did wrong and maybe some advice on better ways to understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did it work when you ran it? If so then you're good!

Comment: You're close.  Take a look at what you're doing in the `n==0` condition: are you sure that does the same things as the non recursive method? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this recursive solution is not correct.

For every positive `n`, you're just return `rectFact(n-1)`, which will recourse until you reach `0`, at which point it will return. In other words, your function will always return `0`. You're missing the part where you **multiply** the current `n` with `rectFact(n-1)`. Additionally, note that `0!` is 1, not 0:

```
public static int recFact(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return n * recFact(n-1);
    }
}
```

And finally, since the `if` clause returns, the `else` is somewhat redundant. This doesn't affect the method's correctness, of course, but IMHO the code looks cleaner without it:

```
public static int recFact(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * recFact(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive version does no multiplication, and it will return zero for any input.  So no, you didn't do it right.

But, the recursive version DOES recurse, so you have that going for you!  To understand what's going wrong, walk through a very simple case.

Client calls `recFact(3)`
This will return to client `recFact(2)`
Which will return to above `recFact(1)`
Which will return to above `recFact(0)`
Which will return to above `0`.

There are two major things going wrong:

- Your base case is wrong (zero is too low)
- You're not doing any multiplication

Good attitude about not wanting the solution handed to you!  Hopefully these pointers wil help you figure it out.

EDIT: Apparently I misunderstood your grammar and you did want the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Any recursive function needs three things:

1. **The terminating condition**: This tells the function when to stop calling itself. This is very important to avoid infinite recursion and avoid stack overflow exceptions.
2. **The actual processing**: You need to run the actual processing within each function. In your non recursive case, this was `result = result * n`. **This is missing from your recursive version!**
3. **A collector/agggregator variable**: You need some way to store the partial result of the recursive calls below you. So you need some way to return the result of `recFact` so that you can include it in processing higher up in the call chain. Note that you say `return recFact(n - 1)` but in the definition `recFact` returns `void`. That should probably be an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Based from your example you are missing the `return type` of your `recFact` which is `int`

Also `recFact` will always return 0 because you are not multiplying  `n` each time to the recursion call of the method.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out of your day to explain this to me it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to write recursive routines. One is the "standard" way that we all are taught. This is one entry point that must first check to see if the recursive chain is at an end (the escape clause). If so, it returns the "end of chain" value and ends the recursion. If not at the end, it performs whatever calculation it needs to get a partial value according to the level and then calls itself passing a value the next increment closer to the end of the chain.

```
private final int InitialValue = 15;
System.out.println( "Fact(" + InitialValue + ") = " + recFact( InitialValue ) );

public int recFact( int val ){
    if( val < 2 ){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return recFact( val - 1 ) * val; // recursive call
    }
}

//Output: "Fact(15) = 2004310016"
```

In regular recursion, a partial answer is maintained at each level which is used to supplement the answer from the next level. In the code above, the partial answer is `val`. When first called, this value is `15`. It takes this value and multiplies it by the answer from Fact(14) to supply the complete answer to Fact(15). Fact(14) got its answer by multiplying 14 by the answer it got from Fact(13) and so on.

There is another type of recursion called tail recursion. This differs in that partial answers are passed to the next level instead of maintained at each level. This sounds complicated but in actuality, make the recursion process much simpler. Another difference is that there are two routines, one is non recursive and sets up the recursive routine. This is to maintain the standard API to users who only want to see (and should only have to see)

```
answer = routine( parameter );
```

The non-recursive routines provides this. It is also a convenient place to put one-time code such as error checking. Notice in the standard routine above, if the user passed in -15 instead of 15, the routine could bomb out. That means that in production code, such a test must be made. But this test will be performed every time the routine is entered which means the test will be made needlessly for all but the very first time. Also, as this must return an integer value, it cannot handle an initial value greater than 19 as that will result in a value that will overflow the 32-bit integer container.

```
public static final int MaxFactorialSeq = 20;
private final int InitialValue = 15;
System.out.println( "Fact(" + InitialValue + ") = " + recFact( InitialValue ) );

public int recFact( int value ){
    if( value < 0 || value > MaxFactorialSeq ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Factorial sequence value " + value + " is out of range." );
    }
    return recFact( value, 1 ); // initial invocation
}

private int recFact( int val, int acc ){
    if( val < 2 ){
        return acc;
    }
    else{
        return recFact( val - 1, acc * val ); // recursive call
    }
}

//Output: "Fact(15) = 2004310016"
```

Notice the public entry point contains range checking code. This is executed only once and the recursive routine does not have to make this check. It then calls the recursive version with an initial "seed" of 1.

The recursive routine, as before, checks to see if it is at the end of the chain. If so, it returns, not 1 as before, but the accumulator which at this point has the complete answer. The call chain then just rewinds back to the initial entry point in the non-recursive routine. There are no further calculations to be made as the answer is calculated on the way down rather than on the way up.

If you walk though it, the answer with standard recursion was reached by the sequence 15*14*13*...*2*1. With tail recursion, the answer was reached by the sequence 1*15*14*...*3*2. The final answer is, of course, the same. However, in my test with an initial value of 15, the standard recursion method took an average of 0.044 msecs and the tail recursion method took an average of 0.030 msecs. However, almost all that time difference is accounted for by the fact that I have the bounds checking in my standard recursion routine. Without it, the timing is much closer (0.036 to 0.030) but, of course, then you don't have error checking.

Not all recursive routines can use tail recursion. But then, not all recursive routines should be. It is a truism that any recursive function can be written using a loop. And generally should be. But a Factorial function like the ones above can never exceed 19 levels so they can be added to the lucky few.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with recursion is that to understand recursion you must first understand recursion.

A recursive function is a function which calls itself, or calls a function which ultimately calls the first function again.

You have the recursion part right, since your function calls itself, and you have an "escape" clause so you don't get infinite recursion (a reason for the function not to call itself).

What you are lacking from your example though is the actual operation you are performing.

Also, instead of passing a counter, you need to pass your counter and the value you are multiplying, and then you need to return said multiplied value.

```
public static long recFact(int n, long val)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return val;
    }
    else
    {
        return recFact(n-1, val) * n;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need two parameters, and it is unclear what the expected usage is here.  What are the definitions of `n` and val`?  What would a call look like to determine the factorial of 3?